# Recovering Missing Folder

Tags: document-library

Hi just i've noticed a weird situation on SharePoint library, where a specific folder within a folder is missing with no trace, but i can see some documents within the main folder. How do i recover the missing folder? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing folder ought to be recoverable from the recycle bin.

If it's not there, it may be located in the site collection (aka 2nd stage) recycle bin. Provided that is configured in your environment.

Otherwise, you may need to restore the missing folder from backup.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the library up with Windows Explorer mode. You should be able to see the folders from there. Make sure that you have the folder options to show hidden folders. If folder name starts with an underscore (_), the folder will not show up on SharePoint.